# Change the Type of a Template Class

Tags: c++, templates, types

As an example in Ruby (1.8)

```
i = 4
i.class => fixnum

i += 1.3
i.class => float
```

Can this be achieved in C++?

for instance

```
template<class T>
struct Number {};

Number<int> foo;

foo.changeTypeToFloat(); // <-- Possible?

// foo now Float?
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: A headache perhaps. Just wanted to know if it was possible. I come to C++ from ruby, and keep trying to do stuff like this.

Comment: it’s just not clear what exactly you want. Do you want to perform a cast? Do you want to change the type of a variable proper (keep in mind that C++ is statically typed!)? Do you want to get a “related” type of your class template `Number`, given an instance of it that is a `Number<int>`? The first and third are absolutely possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ is a statically-typed language.  A variable has a fixed type.  The best you can do at the language level is a conversion to a new variable, e.g.:

```
int i = 5;
float f = static_cast<float>(i);
```

Alternatively, you could write a variant class, and have the conversion handled internally.  But this would really be syntactic sugar for the above.

Answer (score 3):

Like others say, in C++ this can't be done. The issue is not specific to class templates, though. But there are some workarounds that work in some scenarios.

---

You can use `boost::variant<>` to do what you want

```
boost::variant<int, float> v;
v = 0; // v is now storing an int
v = 0.f; // v is now storing a float

struct A { 
  typedef void result_type;
  void operator()(int i) const {
    // process the int
  }
  void operator()(float f) const {
    // process the float
  }
};

// If v stores an int, it calls the int version. 
// Otherwise it calls the float version. 
boost::apply_visitor(A(), v);
```

See [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/variant.html).

---

You can use lexical scoping to make a new variable that hides the name of the other. This is usable when you just want the name to change its meaning, not necessarily the previous object. An important difference is that this changes things at compile time only. `boost::variant` is able to track its stored type at runtime.

```
int i = 0; // i now refers to an int variable
{
  float i = 0.f; // i now refers to a float variable
}
// i refers again to an int variable.
```

---

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, objects can't change their type at run time.

However, ere is a rough equivalent of a possibility

```
template<class T> 
struct Number {
   template<class U> operator U(){
      U temp;
      // conversion code typically using casts e.g.
      return temp;
   }
};
```

This lets you write code such as

```
template<class T>
struct A{
   template<class U> operator U(){
      return U();
   }
};


int main(){
   A<int> a1;
   float f1 = a1;    // convert a1 to float equivalent and so on.
   A<float> f2 = a1; // convert a1 of type A<int> to A<float>
}
```

Comment: That doesn't really do what the OP is intending.  I think he wants to actually modify the type of `foo` itself.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: Oh, Actually without knowing Ruby, this post is just my guess about something that may be roughly equivalent. However if he is looking at changing the type of an object at run time, it is not possible. It may be possible however to do some user defined conversions that may give rough equivalent of what is desired.

Answer (score 0):

Nope you cant.

However you can have a very awkward solution involving `union` / overloading the `=` operator which i haven't tried out. So i cant say it'll work.

Comment: Problem with `union` is that you can't have destructors there.

Comment: @Billy: True, but you can embed the `union` in a `struct`, and the `struct` destructor can perform whatever cleanup is needed.

Answer (score 0):

What follows is a direct answer to the question, as asked. As comments on the question suggest, it would be interesting to know why you are asking it, i.e., what you are trying to achieve.

As Oli writes in his answer, C++ is statically typed so no, the type of a variable can't be changed at runtime.

However, if you know in advance the set of types you want for your variable (from your example `int` and `float`), you could declare a variable whose type is "int or float". This is the `union` solution other answers allude to. However, `union`s have their quirks and are pretty error-prone. Moreover, a union alone is usually not enough, as some information about the currently held type is usually necessary.

There comes [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/variant.html), which is a "discriminated union" (a union which "knows" what type it is currently holding). It allows you to write something like:

```
// Warning: off the top of my head, not compiled, less tested
boost::variant<int, float> int_or_float;

// Variants initialize by default as the first type in their list,
// so int_or_float is currently holding an int
assert(int_or_float.which() == 0);

int_or_float = 0.1;

// Now holding a float
assert(int_or_float.wich() == 1);
```